# Вывод звука на внешнюю карту от рута в linux'е

Tags: linux, аудио, raspberry-pi, root

Есть приложение, которое играет звуки. После настройки файла /etc/asound.conf в котором назначаются приоритеты звуковых карт, все происходит как нужно, - запускаю от пользователя приложение - звук идет во внешнюю карту.

Проблема в том, что мне нужно запускать эту программу как сервис, для этого я зарегистрировал ее в systemd. Все ок, приложение запускается при включении raspberry, но звук идет во внутреннюю звуковую карту.

Чуть позже я понял, что проблема именно в том, что запуская от рута, например через sudo, звук идет во внутреннюю.

Как сделать так, чтобы и от рута звук шел куда нужно?

Использую дистрибутив https://blokas.io/patchbox-os

Comment: Так не запускайте от суперпользователя, делов-то!

Comment: @digital_tutorials  Проблема не в том, что "от рута", а в том, что *root* и рядовой пользователь имеют разные программные окружения. И в ENV от *root* не хватает чего-то, что есть у рядового пользователя. Совет: выполните команду *env* из под обычного пользователя и из под *root*. Посмотрите, в чём там отличие, касательно alsa. Добавьте недостающие ENV переменные в скрипт, который запускает Ваше приложение под *root*. Я думаю - всё отработает нормально.

Comment: да скорее всего играет от пользователя через пульсаудио. Запустите пульсаудио от рута

Comment: а вообще я такие сервисы в systemd/user загоню

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно было вывод приложения переключить на `alsa`.

В моем случае командой `pd -alsa`.

Alsa, как выяснилось, запускается с системой, а `jack`, на который все шло по-умолчанию, запускался с пользователем.